# Programmatically access window created from story board

Tags: macos, cocoa, swift

If I create an OS X app using Xcode 6. What's the best way to programmatically access the UIWindow inside the Window Controller (that's instantiated from the Story Board).

**More Info**

What I'm trying to do is set the `UIWindow.titleVisibility` property (in combination with the "Unified Title and Toolbar" option)

**Solution**

Using @Fr33g's advice, what I really needed to do was create a class based on `NSWindowController` and set this as the *Custom Class* in the Story Board for the Window Controller object.

I was then able to override the `windowDidLoad` and access the `window` object in there to set the `titleVisibility` property.

The toolbar now displays in line with the window controls!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to access the view of a ViewController or what's actually your intention? I'm not aware of a **WindowController**, but of **ViewControllers**. However you can get an array with all UIWindow objects associated to your app by using:

```
[UISharedApplication sharedApplication].windows
```

The windows are ordered from back to front by the window level. Nevertheless I'm not quite sure what you want to do. Perhaps you could be a little more precise.

If you instantiate a ViewController from the storyboard, you can access the view by simply using:

```
yourViewController.view
```